# Google play upload failed because of google play service version

Tags: android, apk, google-play

```
    Upload failed
    You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 6111000. You need touse version 5100000 or lower.
Warnings
You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 6111000. This will only work with Android API levels of 9 and above. It is discouraged to use this Google Play services version unless you have set the minSdkVersion in your manifest to 9 or higher.
```

How to fix this error other than increasing minSdk to 9 ? I m using eclipse for making the apk.

Comment: Choose a lower Google Play Services version number? Try 5.2.08, 5.0.89, 5.0.77, etc.

Comment: Here error it self represent you to how to solve your problem,So try to change google play services version to 5100000 or define minSdkVersion value 9 or higher in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @stkent : How to choose the version using eclipse ?

Comment: You should be able to select a version wherever you are declaring your dependencies (pom if on maven, build.gradle if on gradle, etc.) Gradle example would look something like

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
}`

Answer (score 3):

Just download the old version [here](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5089000_r19.zip), and then import it to your project.

Dont forget to remove the reference from the old version from your project.

Now google play will accept your app.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the latest `Play Service version (6.1)` which start rolling out today.
The new `Play Service (4.0+)` only supported on `Android 2.3+`

You have two options:
1- Use `Play Service For Froyo`. (not recommended at all)
2- Update The `minSdkVersion` in your manifest to `9`

PS: also I recommended you to use `Play Service 5.X` instead of `6.1`. it start rolling out today and it need about two weeks to be installed on all users devices.

Comment: Play service version 6.1 is rolling out means it is being installed automatically on user devices connected to internet. There is no sure way to tell if users have the latest version of play service. Should I be making sure programmatically if users have the required minimum version of play service on their phones?

Comment: Of-curse you have to check the play service version on the user device and If he has an older version you have to ask him to update it. You can do that easily by http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29

Comment: So i have two options - either confirm that play service version is available if not make user install it. Or use an old play service version. It seems a lot of folks don't implement play services check in their apps. From what i am reading one should always check for play service version. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this problem first one change the target sdk but that one of course you have mentioned not to use. The other one in my opinion would be to update your sdk and from google-> google playservices-> get the google play and update it in your project.
     I hope this will work.

Comment: I have updated to version 20 which is the latest and is giving the problem.

Comment: @Vihaan there is an alternative but in that case you have to hardcode the value you want to. Go to this file @integer/google_play_services_version and update the value you want to.

Comment: @Akshat Sharma, No No Nooo. dont do that